# How to Set Yes/No field on selected list items (if/else) using JavaScript in SharePoint 2013

Tags: list, js

In SharePoint 2013, "Discussion" list, I have created a button "fix/unfix" (Yes/No type field) discussion. But the script only works the second time and subsequent times. This script checks the value 0 or 1 and changes to the opposite. I'm not very good at scripting, so please show me what is my mistake.

```
function fieldTest() {
          var ctx = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
          var olist = ctx.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('discussion');
          var oitem = olist.getItemById(1);
          ctx.load(oitem, "fix");
          ctx.executeQueryAsync(function () {
                    check = oitem.get_item("fix");
                    if (!check) {
                             oitem.set_item("fix", true);
                    }
                    else {
                             oitem.set_item("fix", false);
                    }
                    oitem.update();    
                    });  
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you add another `executeQuery` after `oitem.update();` this will work.

The reason it works on the second+ run is because the queued update then will be part of your initial executeQuery!

Modified, the end of your script should look like this:

```
                    oitem.update();    
                    ctx.executeQueryAsync();
                    });  
}
```

Comment: Great! It all worked! I could not even imagine it, what i can use "ctx.executeQueryAsync ()" again. 2 days I rack my brains.
Thank you very much, I will take note of this!

Comment: Glad to be of help!